# Canvas setBackgroundImage from localhost using Fabric JS

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I am trying use input element to load the image and want to set it as a background image for canvas. I am using Fabric JS.

Following is what I have tried

```
$(function(){
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
   $('#importimage').on('change', function(e){
    //method 1
    imageUrl = $(this).val();
    imageUrl = petUtil.getImage(imageUrl);
    _canvas = canvas;
    fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl , function(image)
    {
        image.set({ left:left , top:top , angle:angle , cornersize:10 });

        top_shiv = $('.upper-canvas').attr('height');
        left_shiv = $('.upper-canvas').attr('width');
        top= top_shiv/5;
        left= _canvasWidth/4;

        image.set({left:left , top:top , 
        width:window.newwidth,height:window.newheight });                           
        image.scale(scale).setCoords();
        _canvas.add(image);
        _canvas.setWidth(window.newwidth);
        _canvas.setHeight(window.newheight);    

        _canvas.renderAll();    
    }, {  crossOrigin: 'Anonymous' });




   //method 2
   var file = e.target.files[0];
   alert(file);
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(f) {
      var data = f.target.result;
      fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
            canvas.setHeight(100);
            canvas.setWidth(100);
            canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
      });
   };
});
});
```

both of the methods are not working   jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/upatg6ge/12/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add background image with fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010057/add-background-image-with-fabric-js)

Comment: The answer code is already included in my code still it is not working....

Comment: Can you make a fiddle/snippet? and which version are you using?

Comment: There is no property like `window.newheight` and `window.newwidth` or manually you are setting this else it will be `undefined`?

Comment: @Durga I tried after removing it but still it doesn't work , here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/upatg6ge/9/

Comment: @Durga https://jsfiddle.net/upatg6ge/13/

Comment: Check updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upatg6ge/16/), and before asking question don't forget to debug the code and check console for error(F12)

Comment: @Durga thank you very much, can you please tell what is the problem?

Comment: `document.getElementById(id)` JS(line:3) provide what the `id` is, it was throwing error, check in console.

Comment: Mark the question as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Just add one line below reader.onload callback like this :

```
var file = e.target.files[0];
alert(file);
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(f) {
  var data = f.target.result;
  fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function(img) {
        canvas.setHeight(100);
        canvas.setWidth(100);
        canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
  });
};
// newly added line :
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```