# How to add image background in in FabricJS canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, fabricjs

I try to create a canvas with FabricJS. i use below code for my source, but now i want my canvas area has a backgroung image. How am i do it?
My source code:

[Source code]`enter code here`(http://jsfiddle.net/77vg88mc/34/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add background image with fabric.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010057/add-background-image-with-fabric-js)

Answer (score 1):

You can Simply add the following code to add a background image to your canvas

```
canvas.setBackgroundImage('path/to/img', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
  // Needed to position backgroundImage at 0/0
  originX: 'left',
  originY: 'top'
});
```

There are more parameters to change the position, angle, opacity etc. Please read the documentation for more parameters: [FabricJSDocs](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#setBackgroundImage)